# Problem in Retrieving Data of Current user in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

I have two tables in database

1. local with (ID,comment,entry_by).
2. tb_users with ID and rest info about users

I want to retrieve back **comments** of current logged in user in controller

Controller :

```
public function getIndex( Request $request )
{

    $logeduser= Auth::user()->id;
    $comment = DB::table('local')->select('org_id', 'comment')->where('entry_by', '=', '$logeduser')->get();

    return view('dashboard.index', $comment);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($comment as $comm)
    {{$comm->comment}}
@endforeach
```

it does not work without any error

Comment: Check ypur table name and make sure data is present in the table for logged in user.

Comment: how are you selecting `org_id` from your `local` table when it only has 3 columns with no `org_id`?

Answer (score 1):

Your Query is searching in 'entry_by' for the string '$logeduser'

try this

```
public function getIndex( Request $request )
{

    $logeduser= Auth::user()->id;
    $comment = DB::table('local')->select('org_id', 'comment')->where('entry_by', '=', $logeduser)->get();

    return view('dashboard.index', $comment);
}
```

remove the quotes around your variable

Answer (score 0):

You must edit your controller code as given below

```
public function getIndex( Request $request )
{

    $logeduser= Auth::user()->id;
    $comments = DB::table('local')->select('comment')->where('entry_by', $logeduser)->get();

    return view('dashboard.index', compact('comments'));
}
```

and your view must have

```
@foreach ($comments as $comm)
    {{ $comm->comment }}
@endforeach
```